# Помогите записать значение в сессию при помощи input PHP

Tags: php, сессия

Добрый день! Помогите записать в `сессию` значение из поля `input`.
Хост дает 1 час на сессии, мне какраз этого время хватает.

Интересует что бы в инпут ввести например `ololo` и сделать переменную с этим значением (`$ololo`) которая будт действовать час.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input name="" value="">
<input name="" value="записать">
</form>
```

Comment: в чем сложность то? `$ololo = $_POST['input_field']; $_SESSION['my_var'] = $ololo`

Comment: сложность в том что я не знаю потому и спрашиваю)

Comment: дак вы прочитайте как работать с формами и сессиями. в документации все есть вроде.

Comment: вроде есть всё, вроде прочита, было бы мне понятно не спрашивал бы

Comment: При обновлении страницы удаляется

Comment: Народ помогите, не получается ничего

Answer (score 1):

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['inputFieldName'])) { 
    $_SESSION['input'] = $_POST['inputFieldName'];
}
```

You're welcome.

Итого, значение текстового поля будет сохранено в переменной $_SESSION['input']